# Twitter Bootstrap: pull-right class only working in Firefox for input-group

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, css-float

This HTML, styled with Bootstrap, displays differently in Firefox than it does in Chrome and Safari. In Firefox, as I would expect from the "pull-right" class, the elements float to the right, taking up minimal space. In Chrome and Safari, there's no floating. The elements span the whole width of the screen. If I delete the input-group-btn element the problem is mysteriously fixed but, this destroys the style I want.

```
<div class="pull-right">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid" placeholder="Search" name="new_tag" ng-model="search.$" onkeypress="return disableEnterKey(event)" type="text">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a JSfiddle (compare it in Firefox to Safari or Chrome) http://jsfiddle.net/chvg8v9z/1/

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/chvg8v9z/6/

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4" style="float: right;">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid" placeholder="Search" name="new_tag" ng-model="search.$" onkeypress="return disableEnterKey(event)" type="text">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

You could adjust the number of columns and sizes.

Comment: I wish these browsers would render it as Firefox does, because it's definitely more elegant without having to add the column classes, which don't return the exact same results (say I didn't want the input field to stretch with the screen size). But I guess this gets the job done. Thanks!